# Confusing sentence construction

Tags: sentence-construction, parsing

> London(CNN) - If allied leaders had hoped that US President Donald Trump's presence at a summit in the London area marking the 70th anniversary of the alliance this week would promote unity among old friends they probably left disappointed.

1. Where is the end of if clause?
2. Which is the subject of "would"?
3. Why the clause "they probably left disappointed" can be placed at the end of the sentence just like that without a conjunction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really expanded "if... then..." statement, where the conjunction "then" is elided.

The short version is:

> "**If** allied leaders had hoped that Trump's presence [at the summit] would promote unity, **(then)** they probably left disappointed."

So the answers to your questions are:

1. The if clause runs all the way through "... old friends"
2. "presence" is the subject of "would"
3. The "then" in if-then statements is optional: see [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6724/can-i-use-an-if-clause-without-then) at the English Stack Exchange.